# 外部のHTMLファイルをjestで読み込む方法

Tags: javascript, html, jestjs

JESTフレームワークでテストを実施したいです。
[JESTドキュメント](https://jestjs.io/docs/ja/tutorial-jquery)では下のように`document.body.innerHTML`によってHTMLを書き込んでいます。
`document.body.innerHTML`を使わずに、外部のHTMLファイルをそのまま参照する方法はないのでしょうか。

```
// Set up our document body
document.body.innerHTML =
  '<div>' +
  '  <span id="username" />' +
  '  <button id="button" />' +
  '</div>';
```

---

I'd like to find the way to read HTML file in JavaScript file.
For example, in https://jestjs.io/docs/ja/tutorial-jquery, we directly write some HTML contents like above.

But I'd like to read one HTML file, instead of `document.body.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

存在します。

### 構造

ディレクトリ構成を次のようにします。

```
.
├── src/__tests__
│   ├── index.test.ts
│   └── index.html
└── jest.config.js
```

#### パッケージ類

```sh
yarn add -D jest jsdom jquery
```

#### jest.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  "automock": false,
  "unmockedModulePathPatterns": ["<rootDir>/node_modules/*"],
  "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules"],
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "jsx", "node"],
  "testMatch": ["**/__tests__/*.test.+(js|jsx)"],
  "collectCoverage": true
};
```

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>jest document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="title">hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

### 方法1

1つ目の方法は、`fs`ライブラリを利用することです。

```js
// index.test.ts
const fs = require("fs");

// もしbody要素だけであれば
document.body.innerHTML = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/index.html", { encoding: "utf-8" }); 

// <head>タグ内の要素も変更したい場合
document.querySelector("html").innerHTML = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/index.html", { encoding: "utf-8" });
```

とやればよいでしょう。ただし、今回の質問は明確に `document.body.innerHTML` を使わずにとあるので、方法2を紹介します。

### 方法2

[ドキュメント](https://jestjs.io/docs/ja/tutorial-jquery)の下部にあるように、Jest内部では[JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom)を利用してDOMをManupulationしています。
つまり、JSDOMのAPIを利用すれば今回の質問に対する答えが見つかります。

#### `fromeFile`を利用する

例えば、`fromFile`というAPIを利用する場合次のように書けます。

```js
// index.test.ts
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const { fromFile } = JSDOM;

describe("test suite", () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    console.log(__dirname + "/index.html");
    const jsdom = await fromFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    // jestがglobalに定義してあるwindowのdocumentをoverrideする
    Object.defineProperty(window, "document", {
      writable: true,
      value: jsdom.window.document,
    });
  });

  it("test with fromFile", async () => {
    const $ = require("jquery"); // jQueryはdocumentがセットされた後に読み込む
    expect(document.querySelector(".title").textContent).toEqual("hello world");
    expect($("h1").text()).toEqual("hello world");
  });
});
```

内部的には方法1で紹介したような`fs.writeFile`が走っていますが、fromFileの第2引数で[vm](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html)の実行をある程度制御することが出来ます。

#### `fromURL`を利用する

HTMLをURLから取得することも出来ます。ただし、HTTP Requestが走ってしまうので叩き過ぎには気をつけましょう。

```js
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const { fromURL } = JSDOM;

describe("test suite", () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const jsdom = await fromURL("https://example.com/");
    // jestがglobalに定義してあるwindowのdocumentをoverrideする
    Object.defineProperty(window, "document", {
      writable: true,
      value: jsdom.window.document,
    });
  });
  it("test with fromURL", async () => {
    const $ = require("jquery"); // jQueryはdocumentがセットされた後に読み込む
    expect($("h1").text()).toEqual("Example Domain");
  });
});
```

### 参考

- https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#fromfile
- https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#fromurl